# SAPUI5 get oData model from table binding

Tags: binding, model, odata, sapui5

I have binded a Table using oData like below.

```
<Table id="myTableID" 
            class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" 
            items="{Items}"
            noDataText="{i18n>NoDataText}" 
            updateFinished="onUpdateFinished"
            width="auto">
```

Now I need to retrieve this oData model from the view rather than calling the web service again.

I have tried the below,

```
var path = this.getView().getElementBinding().getPath();
var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
```

which returns the model from the parent view.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `this.getView().byId("myTableID").getModel();`

Comment: I used this and still getting the parent model.

Comment: You should be getting the model attached to the table. If the same model is also attached to the view, then it will be the same indeed

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want only the items that are bound to the table.

```
var sPath = oTable.getBindingPath("items");
```

This gives you the path that you have bound to the `items` aggregation.

```
var oModelObject = oTable.getModel().getProperty(sPath);
```

This fetches only the table bound objects from your model

**Edit** `oTable` is your table object. `var oTable = this.getView().byId("myTableID");`

Comment: I'm getting the correct binding path but the model is returning a null value. I think this should work ideally but not in my case

Comment: @harini88 Then let's find out what your case is.. do you have a small JSBin example? I used this one to find the solution: https://jsbin.com/zotama/1/edit?html,console,output

Comment: I am also facing same issue, don't know why. but I have iterated through model for each path I have received in context via getBinding("items").getCurrentContexts()